# google bigquery bq command syntax error

Tags: google-bigquery

Could somebody explain me why I am getting an syntax error in the following code:

```
$ bq query --allow_large_results --destination_table=clients.tab_cl1 "SELECT * from adagency-167918:sourcedataset.src_table$20170516 where advertiserid=1 and timestamp="2017-05-16""
```

and this is the error I am getting:

> Error in query string: Error processing job 'adagency-167918:bqjob_r215d56938dbaa2b7_0000015c1a4c2932_1': Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 31.
>       Was expecting:

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the problem is unrelated to using `bq`, actually, although the `$` is problematic. When you are using legacy SQL, you need to use `[` and `]` to escape the table name if the project includes a hyphen. For example,

```
[your-project:dataset.table]
```

With [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), you use backticks:

```
`your-project.dataset.table`
```

So your query should be:

```
bq query --allow_large_results \
  --destination_table=clients.tab_cl1 \
  "SELECT * from [adagency-167918:sourcedataset.src_table\$20170516] where advertiserid=1 and timestamp=timestamp('2017-05-16')"
```

Comment: bq query --allow_large_results \
>   --destination_table=clients.tab_cl1 \
>   "SELECT * from adagency-167918:sourcedataset.src_table$20170516 where advertiserid=1 and timestamp='2017-05-16'"
Error in query string: Error processing job 'adagency-167918:bqjob_r245ac0dd9b13f50_0000015c1b9c7d0d_1': Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 23.
Was expecting:
<EOF>